# How to add value from Model class to ArrayList

Tags: android, arraylist, addition

I am trying to add into my `ArrayList` some value of 2 number sum. In `Model class` i have `getters and setters`, `constructor` and `Method` witch calculates two number sum, `set` and `return` the new result. I have no idea how to `get` the result and `add` the result into `ArrayList`

Model class:

```
public class SumOfTwoNumbers {
private String result;
private Context context;

public SumOfTwoNumbers (String result) {
    this.result = result;
}

public SumOfTwoNumbers (int x, int y){
    int res = x + y;
    result = String.valueOf(res);
    setResult(result);
}

public String getResult() {
    return result;
}

public void setResult(String result) {
    this.result = result;
}
}
```

In Activity I do something like this and i know that, it is wrong:

```
SumOfTwoNumbers sum = new SumOfTwoNumbers();

ArrayList<SumOfTwoNumbers> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
arrayList.add(sum.getResult());
```

I would like to get result and add it to ArrayList.

Can someone tell me in what i have to think?

Hope i explaned well my problem.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your implementation seems wrong. As model class should always be plain java text. But here you are storing context also, which possibly cause memory leaks.

And, in arrayList part you add only those objects to arrayList for which you have made array list.

```
ArrayList<SomeClass> list = new ArrayList<>();
AnotherClass a = new AnotherClass();
list.add(a); // this is completely wrong;

SomeClass b= new SomeClass();
list.add(b); //this is perfectly fine
```

Hope you got your answer.

Comment: You should've written that as a comment, not an answer !!

Comment: I just did edit my question, hope now i explaned clearly.

Comment: Sorry about that. but now I have editted that to an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having a hard time understanding your question, but I guess you're looking to create a list like this? (If your getResult method returns an Integer)

```
SumOfTwoNumbers sum = new SumOfTwoNumbers(1,4);

ArrayList<Integer> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
arrayList.add(sum.getResult());
```